# Seeking in video.js player not possible in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, video.js

I ran into this problem a couple of times: Seeking through videos within the video.js player is possible in any browser except chrome. That means, clicking on the progress bar won't change the current position of the video.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, the problem was the server delivering the video with the HTTP status Code `OK (200)`. Instead, it should return `Partial Content (206)`.

To check whether the server is the problem, embed the test video as in the online example on videojs.com, i.e. load the Disney video from http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4 instead of your own server.

Comment: The simple idea of using the link to the example video is actually super helpful, thank you.

Comment: Is that all that is required? Just change the status code to 206?

Comment: @vbNewbie, I can only tell you that in my case it was.

Comment: @sk904861, one more thing sorry. The video stream being served by your server, is it as a full stream or in partial byte ranges?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was more than four years ago and I'm not aware of the details anymore.

Comment: this helped A LOT. it also helped me understand more on inner working of said standard

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome it is browser issue.

THe chrome browser buffering the video before we set the current time ..
 But firefox and IE are not buffering when page loads.

So we can set the currentTime(10).